# How do I execute a very long dynamic sql statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I remember back in the day I would make a whole wack of `nvarchar(4000)` vars, check the length of them as they grew, switch them out as they filled up and then concatenate the whole mess together for the exec call. I was wondering if there was an easier way of doing it.

Thanks!

Edit:

Code Sample, shows me screwing up the case statement

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = CAST(N'SELECT ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @Index INT
SELECT @Index = 0

WHILE (@Index < 1000)
BEGIN
 SELECT @sql = CAST(@sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(N'          ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST( CASE @Index WHEN 1 THEN N' ' END AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
 SELECT @Index = @Index + 1
END
SELECT @sql = CAST(@sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT LEN(@sql)
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I might not understand the question, but why not use nvarchar(MAX) variable(s) - (SQL 2005 and up)?

Comment: What's the question?  Dynamic SQL means string concatenation...

Comment: @Tommy - add your comment as an answer. Spot on

Comment: @AdaTheDev - someone beat me to it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) accepts a parameter of type NVARCHAR(MAX) which can grow up to 2GB. There is no need for any gimmick, since the NVARCHAR(MAX) type supports all the string operations (concatenation, replacing etc):

> `[ @statement= ] statement`
>
> ```
> Is a Unicode string that contains a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
> ```
>
> statement must be either a Unicode
>   constant or a Unicode variable. More
>   complex Unicode expressions, such as
>   concatenating two strings with the +
>   operator, are not allowed. Character
>   constants are not allowed. If a
>   Unicode constant is specified, it must
>   be prefixed with an N. For example,
>   the Unicode constant N'sp_who' is
>   valid, but the character constant
>   'sp_who' is not. **The size of the
>   string is limited only by available
>   database server memory. On 64-bit
>   servers, the size of the string is
>   limited to 2 GB, the maximum size of
>   nvarchar(max).**

Comment: Lets hope I get to deploy this application on SQL Server 2005 +

Comment: Just be mindful of some of the string functions: 

DECLARE @x nvarchar(max)
SET @x = REPLICATE('a',10000)
SELECT LEN(@x) -- 8000 
-- needs to be SET @x = REPLICATE(CAST('a' AS nvarchar(max)),10000)

Comment: I still can't get my NVARCHAR(MAX) var above 4k characters. :(

Comment: Argh! A case statement was messing me up! Thanks again Remus.

Comment: 64-bit is limited to 2 GB? I thought that was the limit for 32-bit.

Answer (score 3):

`EXEC (@YourSQL)` OR `sp_exectesql` if you wish to continue to build onto your dynamic SQL and execute.