# How do I execute a very long dynamic sql statement on SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, dynamic-sql

I generate an sql string select statement that is around 25k characters long. Unfortunately the production server is SQL 2000.
Is my only option to break the string up into 4k nvarchars?

```
--ex.
DECLARE @s1 NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @s2 NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @s3 NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @s4 NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @s5 NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @s6 NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @s7 NVARCHAR(4000)

--fill nvarchars

EXEC @s1 + @s2 + @s3 + @s4 + @s5 + @s6 + @s7
```

Comment: I posted this before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190423/how-do-i-execute-a-very-long-dynamic-sql-statement but solution was for sql server 2005.

Comment: I was going to suggest posting portions to see if the query could be minimized using WITH statements, but they aren't supported in 2000 :(  Is there no way that can not be trimmed somehow?  I found Oracle's dynamic SQL had issues with how it interpreted whitespace/space characters...

Comment: Hmm, maybe I can create a temp table for the results and add columns one by one...

Comment: Aw damn I'd have to update the rows one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DynamicSQLExec
   @SQL ntext
AS
EXEC (@SQL)
```

You can't declare a text local variable, but you **can** have one be a parameter for a stored procedure.