# How to pass parameter into WITH clause Where Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I use a parameter that consist a string in a where statement within a `with` clause which is bold in the codes. I tried doing that method but its doesn't work.

I have added a parameter called @param nvarchar(max) already.

```
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    **WHERE SalesPersonID IN ('+ @param +')**
)
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID
```

Comment: You have 2 choices, 1. Use dynamic SQL, 2, Use LIKE with the known pattern of @param

Comment: How do I do it with dynamic sql? I tried using SET @sql = 'Select.......' inside the with clause but I don't think it really works. can you show me how to do it your way using dynamic sql?

Comment: Ideally, change your calling convention. Use xml or, ideally, a table-valued parameter, rather than a *string*. Both of the former types are *designed* for holding multiple values, and can be used (relatively) naturally in a query. A string (that I'm guessing is going to be a string containing commas and possible quotation marks) is going to be treated as a single string, here as in most other languages.

Comment: If @param is like '1,2,3' or '1', you can easily create the where condition without dynamic SQL `WHERE ',' + @param + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(SalesPersonID as varchar(10)) + ',%'`

Comment: the @param will be like "'ID 21312','ID 1243213','ID 342342'......." something like that

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a *table* variable instead of a `NVARCHAR`, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @param TABLE (id int)
INSERT INTO @param VALUES (1), (2), (3)

;WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IN (SELECT id FROM @param)
)
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID
```

Alternatively, if `@param` is a comma separated list of numbers you can use a split string function. Then you could use `IN` operator like this:

```
WHERE SalesPersonID IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@param, ',')
```

[**Here**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) is a very good reference on split string functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @param varchar(max) = 'some value'

;WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IN (''+ @param +'')
)
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID
```

or you can achieve this Dynamic query

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But I do receive error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error during data adapter.fill(dataset) line as the parameter consists of a string .

Answer (score 0):

You can change the query to string query, then execute it.

```
    DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQLQuery = 'WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
    AS
    (
        SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
        WHERE SalesPersonID IN (' + @param + ')
    )
    SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
    FROM Sales_CTE
    GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID'

    EXEC(@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: Hi, it does not work thanks as the parameter consists a string. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error during data adapter.fill(dataset) line.

Comment: @newtoasp i modified my answer into string sql query, i think that is the better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have an error with Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Please advice thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Jonathan, you can use dynamic query here as stated below.

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @param = '1,2,5'

SET @query  = 'WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
(
   SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
   FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
   WHERE SalesPersonID IN ('+ @param +')
 )
 SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
 FROM Sales_CTE
 GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID'

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: My main concern now is that my WITH clause is rather long that exceeds 4000character if im putting the whole statement into it. Please advice.

Comment: The max size for a column of type NVARCHAR(MAX) is 2 GByte of storage. So in your case if the parameter size is much larger then you also have to declare param as a NVARCHAR(max).

Comment: @J-D - a `nvarchar(max)` *variable* can store [more than 2GB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611394/maximum-size-of-a-varcharmax-variable). The 2GB limit applies to *columns*.

Comment: isn't it restricted by the number of characters in the SET @QUERY = ' '? it is by size?

Comment: @newtoasp - not *as such*. You have to be careful when [concatenating multiple strings together though](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177561.aspx): "If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur."

Comment: just have a look at this stack question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190423/how-do-i-execute-a-very-long-dynamic-sql-statement

Comment: I have an error with Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Please advice thanks

Comment: Thanks for the above notes on NVARCHAR

Comment: This will help you in your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032425/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-with

Comment: adding a ; does not work for me using dynamic sql tho